# emacs find-grep grep

Tags: emacs, grep, xargs

I try to do a grep on the result of emacs' find-grep, so I use the following command:

find ... | xargs ... | grep -v "include"

The result does show up i the *grep* buffer, but when I press enter on each entry trying to go to that file, emacs says that file does not exist. On the minibuffer, before the full path of the file, there is a ^[[K character. That basically make the the whole file name unrecognizable. I looked through grep's manual, still no sure what I can do about it.

I probably don't have to do this, but I'm just not sure how to pass two pattern, one is for grep and the other one is to inverse grep. (May be regular expression?)

Anyone has any suggestions on this?

**Solution:**

I was doing this on a Cento 5.5 machine. It turns out to be a issue due to the old version of grep. I installed a latest version of grep in my home directory, and everything's good now.

Comment: I got away with it using egrep instead, but I'm wondering if there another way around this.

Comment: Works for me, need more info.  What's the full command you're using?  What happens if you cut/paste the command into a regular terminal?

Comment: full command:
find . -path "*support/*" -prune -o -path "*DICOM/*" -prune -o -type f \( -iname "*.hh" -print0 -or -iname "*.cc" -print0 \) | xargs -0 -e grep -nH --mmap -G "GioMaster"  | grep -v include

Comment: Then when I press enter on one of the entery, it says on the mini prompt:
Find this grep hit in (default ^[[K<path to the file>):

Comment: Press enter on that again, I get:
Cannot find the file `^[[K<full path the file>'

Comment: On terminal, it prints out alright. But it prints out fine in *grep* too, it's just when I try to go to the file through *grep* buffer's entry, that problem shows up.

Comment: So the ^[[K character only shows up in the minibuffer, and never in the \*grep\* buffer?

Comment: No, I don't see it in *grep* buffer. By the way, the system I had problem with is Centos 5.5 at work. After I went home, I tried on my Ubuntu box, and seems to be working. Ahh~~, another reason to hate Centos ...

Comment: You should add your solution as a new answer, and then accept it.

Answer (score 3):

After "debugging" the issue through the comments, this is a solution that should work for you.  Add it to your .emacs and customize it so that the regexp matches the special characters you want to strip from the filename:  `^[[K`

```
(defadvice compilation-find-file (before compilation-find-file-strip-odd-chars activate)
  "Strip the ^[[K in the input string"
  (let ((filename (ad-get-arg 1)))
    (save-match-data
      (when (string-match "^\\[\\[K" filename)
        (ad-set-arg 1 (replace-match "" nil nil filename))))))
```

Comment: Really appreciate that you took the time to figure it out. But after I loaded that defadvice and try to run find-grep, I get the following error message.

Comment: Debugger entered--Lisp error: (invalid-regexp "Unmatched [ or [^")
  string-match("^[[K" "[K/home/optivus/rcai/repos/Optivus/pbts/brain/src/CS_BrainTasksShare.cc")
  compilation-find-file(#<marker at 889 in *grep*> "[K/home/optivus/rcai/repos/Optivus/pbts/brain/src/CS_BrainTasksShare.cc" nil)
  compilation-next-error-function(0 nil)
  next-error-internal()
  compile-goto-error((mouse-2 (#<window 276 on *grep*> 889 (291 . 160) 912640197 nil 889 (41 . 11) nil (4 . 6) (7 . 14))))
  call-interactively(compile-goto-error nil nil)

Comment: My solution to this problem is to install up to date version of grep. The grep package came with Centos 5.5 is quite old, I guess they are not compatible with Emacs. That basically solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but couldn't change my version of grep,
so I used a workaround. The problem seemed to be greps line endings
so I simply run the results of grep through awk
and print them as is.

```
... | grep -v blaa | awk '{print $0}'
```

This fixes the problem for me, though I don't know why.

Comment: I suppose ^[[K  is a control character that awk can recognize, so it just ignores it.